# Setting x-axis and y-axis range on high-level charts?

Tags: python, graph, charts, bokeh, jupyter-notebook

The following chart and indeed many of the high-level charts provided as examples in the Bokeh documentation, suffers from a problem: it creates an unnecessary and visually disorienting space on either side of the plot both in the x-axis and in the y-axis. See, for example, [this example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.0/docs/gallery/area_chart.html).

It would be much more visually appealing if the corners of the chart notched precisely into the edges of the axes (so the bottom left of my area is at the bottom left edge of the chart and the bottom right of my area is at the bottom right edge of the chart). To do this, I expect that I would need to change the `x_range` and `y_range` of the plot to match the ranges for my data.

For low-level `plotting.figure` objects I just have to set `y_range` or `x_range`, but these attributes do not appear to exist for high-level `bokeh.charts` objects.

What are the associated attributes for a high-level chart and how do I set them?

Here is a MWE of a plot with this problem demonstrating what I mean:

```
defaults.width = 800
defaults.height = 400

output_notebook(hide_banner=True)

data = dict(
     python=[2, 3, 7, 5, 26, 221, 44, 233, 254, 265, 266, 267, 120, 111],
     pypy=[12, 33, 47, 15, 126, 121, 144, 233, 254, 225, 226, 267, 110, 130],
     jython=[22, 43, 10, 25, 26, 101, 114, 203, 194, 215, 201, 227, 139, 160],
)

# data = execs_dat

area = Area(data,
            title="Cumulative executive experience at the Wikimedia Foundation",
            stack=True,
            xlabel='',
            ylabel=''
           )

show(area)
```

Here is a visual:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Ok, I've got it wrong the first time. Now that you've added the image I understand that what you want is to limit the range to the stric min/max values of your x/y values. In this case you can simply explicitly set your x_range/y_range. For instance:

```
area.y_range = Range1d(0, 270)
```

If you also want to get more space out of your axis borders then you can refer to my old answer here:

> I'm not entirely sure I understand your question because you asked
>   about axis and the mention ranges... If got your question right you
>   can set your labels to '' (as you did) and set `min_border_bottom` or
>   `min_border_left` to reduce the related space, since `Chart` inherit
>   from `Plot`. So, in your case:
>
> ```
> area.min_border_bottom = area.min_border_left = 0
> ```
>
> That said, there are current discussion to align `Chart` to `Figure`
>   so it can share [at least part of] that API as well.
>
> If that is not your question and you think that `Chart` is not working
>   as it should I'd suggest to either to move the discussion to the
>   [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!forum/bokeh) or [open an issue on github](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) wh

ere it can be better addressed.

Comment: I've attempted to edit for clarity. I do not think this is it, can you take a look again?

Comment: On mobile now (not the best to place answer) but trying give a quick feedback... You should be able to set area.y_range and area.x_range but not pass them as argument. There is currently an open issue for that.

Comment: That worked! Definitely a growth issue, then. Thanks; closing now.